# Recovering layer (*.lyr) file that is missing shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, layer-file

Somebody in the office deleted a point shapefile that has a lyr file as well. How can I recover it? Is there a Script that allows me to recover it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know where that shapefile was located you should be able to recover it from either the Recycle Bin or a system backup. Once restored to its original location the layer file should once again be able to locate it.

If you need to point your layer file at a new data source you can add it to your Table of Contents, use the Source tab of its properties to locate the new source shapefile, and then use Save As Layer File to either overwrite the original or to create another one with a new name.

Comment: Yes but what about the server or over the network would that restore it ?

Comment: You would need to talk to whoever is responsible for your server backups.

Comment: no problem, sir @PolyGeo

Comment: @PROBERT Or you may just need to apply the symbology from the lyr file to the point file in a different location. Lyr files just control symbology and embed the path - there is no data there. If the symbology is good, but the point file is renamed, in a different place, or if the lyr was created on a temporary copy of the file, you can apply the lyr symbology to the correct file and save a new one with an updated path. You cannot recover points or data from a lyr file though - if it's truly gone, as PolyGeo says you have to recover the shapefile itself.

Comment: @ChrisW  - Ok I am not quite sure if this would work. The point featureclass I had saved in the File Geodatabase on the server and I created this as a Layer file within the same folder. I checked the Lyr file and showed me that the data is non-existed.  I am curious if I could copy the lyr file and paste to a different folder and rename the file extension such as .txt and then rename it again in .lyr Would that work ? Thanks.

Comment: @PROBERT No, just changing the extension back and forth doesn't do anything. If the goal is to edit the path in the lyr file you can't - it's a binary file, not a text file. If you add the lyr file and nothing shows up, you can go to the properties > source tab to see where it's looking and change it if the point fc or gdb moved. You can also apply the symbology in the lyr file to a point layer on the symbology tab (import). But if you do not have the original point features *somewhere*, or similar ones with the same attributes, a lyr file cannot help you recover the points in any way.